# Update A multi-valued field in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a lookup table in Access to provide the possible values for a column. Now I need to update this column with the data it had before I converted the column. I am unable to figure out a SQL Query that will work. I keep getting the error "An UPDATE or DELETE query cannot contain a multi-valued field." My research has suggested that I just need to set the value of the column but this always updates 0 records:

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name].Value = 55 WHERE [table_name].ID = 16;
```

I know this query will work if I change it to update a text column, so it is definitely a problem with just this column.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're adding a value to your multi-valued field, use an append query.

```
INSERT INTO table_name( [column_name].Value )
VALUES (55)
WHERE ID = 16;
```

If you want to change one particular value which exists in your multi-valued field, use an UPDATE statement.  For example, to change the 55 to 56 ...

```
UPDATE [table_name]
SET [column_name].Value = 56
WHERE [column_name].Value = 55 And ID = 16;
```

See [Using multivalued fields in queries](https://web.archive.org/web/20110317084101/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001233722#BM8) for more information.

Comment: Nice. In my case I also had to delete first to clear the column out. E.g.: DELETE columnName.Value FROM tableName WHERE columnName.Value > -1;.

Answer (score 5):

I have figured this out! It certainly was counter-intuitive! You have to use an INSERT statement to do the update.

```
-- Update a record with a multi-valued field that has no value
INSERT INTO [table_name] ( [[column_name].[Value] )
VALUES(55)
WHERE [table_name].ID = 16;
```

This confused me because I was expecting an UPDATE statement. I think it actually inserts a record into a hidden table that is used to associate multiple values with this column.

Comment: I think you nailed it.  Under the hood, the multi-valued field is implemented as you described.  But those details are hidden for "convenience"(?).  Anyway this kind of confusion is a good reason to avoid multi-valued fields, IMO.  The only reason I would use them is if working with SharePoint.

Answer (score 3):

I am working with Sharepoint, I created the tables as multi-value fields, ran into the error with my `INSERT INTO` statement, went back to Sharepoint to change to non-multi-value fields, but that didn't fix it.

Recreated the table **without** using multi-value fields, and the `INSERT INTO` worked just fine.

Comment: yep - multi-value fields are best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I gotta say I didn't understand very well your problem but I saw something strange in your query. Try this:

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name]= 55 WHERE [table_name].ID = 16;
```

**UPDATE**:
Look at [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx#BM8) link: it has an example

```
UPDATE Issues 
SET Issues.AssignedTo.Value = 10
WHERE (((Issues.AssignedTo.Value)=6) 
AND ((Issues.ID)=8));
```

> **NOTES**
>
> You should always include a WHERE
> clause that identifies only the
> records that you want to update.
> Otherwise, you will update records
> that you did not intend to change. An
> Update query that does not contain a
> WHERE clause changes every row in the
> table. You can specify one value to
> change.

Comment: That query pops up the ""An UPDATE or DELETE query cannot contain a multi-valued field." error message.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work if the column has an existing value but not when the column does not have a value. In other words, you can only update an existing value.

Comment: @rsrobbins: can't help you more, I'm sorry. My knowledge ends here with multi-valued fileds because I don't use them... so, I hope my post could have helped you in some way and... well, good luck for your problem :)

Comment: @Marco Re: NOTES - it depends what you're doing. I've copied the structure of a table and am investigating how to copy data to this table with multi-valued fields. I inserted all the non-multi-valued fields using an Append query, and figured I could update the mv fields. Now I see I must insert the mv field using an Append query, but I do want to insert data for **all records**. Of course, I'm using an INNER JOIN between the tables, but I suppose technically, you could use WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID and get the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

do not use the .value part

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name] = 55 WHERE [table_name].ID = 16;
```

Comment: I've already posted this solution and he already told me it's not what he needs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Quals (cTypes.[value])
SELECT Quals_ContractTypes.ContractType
FROM Quals_ContractTypes
WHERE (Quals.ID = Quals_ContractTypes.ID_Quals);
```

Comment: Adding a little explanation about where the poster is going wrong with your query would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The Multi-Valued field refers to Access databases that have tables with columns, that allow you to select multiple values, like a Combo Checkbox list.

**THOSE** are the only Access types that SQL cannot work with. I've tested all Access lookup possibilities, including hard-coded values, and lookup tables. They work fine, but if you have a column that has the Allow Multiple select options, you're out of luck. Even using the INSERT INTO as mentioned below, will not work as you'll get a similar but different error, about INSERTing into multi-valued fields.

As mentioned it's best to avoid using such tables outside of Access, and refer to a table specifically for your external needs. Then write a macro/vba script to update the real tables with the data from the "auxiliary" table.